# Looking at the new Rider EAP, does anyone know if its possible to import multiproject?

Tags: c#, rider

I am using Rider to open my dotnet core projects on ubuntu, i cant seem to target a global.json file though, only the project.json files, does anyone know if multi project is possible yet??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you can open a one project (project.json), rider will generate xproj and sln files. And after that you can add other project through solution explorer (Solution -> Add existing project -> select other project.json on by one). After that, save sln file.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a .sln file in your project then Rider should be able to open that.